# Удаление маркера при закрытии балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Здесь пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/ccxLg8yz/

Это на основе примера из документации:  https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout

но добавлена одна строка в функцию clear:

```
map.geoObjects.remove(placemark);
```

При этом теперь при закрытии балуна получаем сообщение в консоль:

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type
>   'Node'.

Ну и если было несколько маркеров, то балун уже перестает отрываться для других маркеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя удалять гео-объект во время работы с его же макетом (или с макетом его балуна).

Подпишитесь на [`GeoObject@balloonclose`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/#event-balloonclose)

```
placemark.events.add('balloonclose', function() { 
  map.geoObjects.remove(placemark);
});
```